# pipeline input is not in cuda device, but its a list[str]

Tags: python, pipeline, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

Trying to run a simple text classification with a pipeline (needs to be in batch processing) is yielding me a device allocation issue.

```
tokenizer_filter = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("salesken/query_wellformedness_score")
tokenizer_kwargs = {'padding':True,'truncation':True,'max_length':512}
model_filter = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("salesken/query_wellformedness_score").to(torch.device("cuda"))

filtering = pipeline("text-classification", model=model_filter, tokenizer=tokenizer_filter, batch_size=8)
scores = filtering(df['content'].tolist(), **tokenizer_kwargs)
```

The simple code above is yielding:

```
Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper_CUDA__index_select)
```

Apparently the input is on CPU (as it is a python list of str) and the model on GPU. How to move the input to GPU?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines) field `device` can be set to `"cuda:0"`. As simple as that.